# Formatting a WD External Drive In Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am trying to format a WD My Book which has been recently swapped from a macmini to a Linux based data server. Using Partitioner, I can see the drive, however, it is showing as 2 entries. One entry is showing the mounted file path, the other is just showing the basics (no FS, no mounting point etc.) I have obviously done a back up of the data already on the drive, but which do I reformat in order for the write permissions to be correct for Linux. (Running OpenSuse 12.3) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with OpenSUSE, but it should have tools like `gparted` / `parted`, or `gnome-disk-utility` (Disks), I use `gparted` for formatting. BUT, are you only formatting the drive because you don't have write permission on the files? Tried writing to files when you're root (logged in, or with `sudo`) or `chown` / `sudo chown`? What is the current format of the drive/partition, HFS+? And you want ext3/4?

Answer (score 0):

Don't format the mounted file path because it probably works with the root directory. The other one should be formattable.

Comment: Understand that, however, the mounted file one is what I will require for the HDD to write to (eventually), my "common sense" says that I ought to do that one as it appears to be the one that the system recognises. However, using kinfo, the only drive that appears is the unmounted one. Soooooo - will your answer still apply? Much appreciated.

Comment: Reformatted the mounted filepath and then re-mounted it. All does appear to be working as I want it. The unmounted drive showing on the window would not format - the partitioner directed me to the mounted one. Following the formatting, the Linux box required me to re-mount it and links that I had set up within the system to archive files work as expected. Thanks for your assistance. *puts on happy hat* :o)